# Skipping over row when I'm trying to fill a csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to build an edgelist for a SNA project using question, answer, and comments from an online course discussion forum.

Here's my code where I build the edgelist:

```
# import libraries
import csv
import collections
from collections import defaultdict

def multi_dimensions(n, type):
  # """ Creates an n-dimension dictionary where the n-th dimension is of type 'type' 
  if n<=1:
    return type()
  return defaultdict(lambda:multi_dimensions(n-1, type))

edgelist = multi_dimensions(2,dict)

csv.field_size_limit(1600000)
f = open('/Users/samuelfinegold/Documents/harvard/edXresearch/snaCreationFiles/time_series/time_series.csv','rU')
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')

for line in reader:
    # edgelist
    if line['types'] == 'Question':
        #print 'T'
        source = line['author_id']
    else:
        edgelist[source]['target'] = line['author_id']
        edgelist[source]['start_time'] = line['time']
```

And here's the csv for context:

```
post_id thread_id   author_id       types   time    votes_up    votes_down  posters
1       0            Jan         Question     3/1/12 10:45  5   1   Jan, Janet, Jack
2       0            Janet       Answer   3/1/12 11:00  2   1   Jan, Janet, Jack
3       0            Jack        Comment      3/2/12 8:00   0   0   Jan, Janet, Jack
4       1            Jason       Question     3/4/12 9:00   3   1   Jason, Jan, Janet
5       1            Jan         Answer   3/7/12 1:00   3   1   Jason, Jan, Janet
6       1            Janet       Answer   3/7/12 2:00   1   2   Jason, Jan, Janet
```

And here's what I'm getting for my edgelist:

```
source  target  time
Jan         Jack    999
Jason   Janet   999
```

I have no idea what's causing the time to differ so much.

Desired output:

```
source     target     start_time
Jan        Janet      3/1/12 11:00
Jan        Jack       3/2/12 8:00
Jason      Jan        3/7/12 1:00
Jason      Janet      3/7/12 2:00
```

Note the times are when the answer or comment was posted. For those familiar with dynamic SNA graphs, you may be wondering why I don't have end times. This is because, for simplicity's sake, I will simply manually add a column with the same end time for each of the posts, meaning the graph will not show any disappearances.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I will edit it now to show you.

Comment: It looks like the CSV file is tab delimited but you have specified comma delimited - this is probably reading the author_id etc. from the comma separated list in the last column - time is beyond the end of the list and maybe 999 is some kind of Null value. Try specifying `delimiter='\t'` in the `csv.DictReader`

Comment: Are you saying that the csv is tab delimited based on the fact that the pasted output looks like it's separated by tabs and not by commas? If so, that's only because I c/p it from a spreadsheet. I believe that it is comma delimited and not tab delimited.

Comment: @goldisfine If the format of the CSV in your question is different than the format of the CSV you are actually using, it might be a good idea to make the CSV example in your question match what you are actually using :)